# Forms validation in Nancy not working with AJAX login requests

Tags: ajax, forms-authentication, nancy

I'm trying to implement an extremely simple spike using Nancy as an alternative to ASP.NET MVC.

It should take a username (no password) and provide meaningful error messages on the same login page without requiring a refresh. If login was successful, the response includes the URL to navigate to.

The POCO for the response looks like this:

```
public class LoginResponseModel
{
    public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }
    public string RedirectUrl { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

The JS handler for the login request:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/login',
        type: "POST",
        data: { UserName: username }
    }).done(function (response) {
        if (response.IsSuccess) {
            showSuccess();
            document.location.href = response.RedirectUrl;
            return;
        }
        showError(response.ErrorMessage);
    }).fail(function (msg) {
        showError("Unable to process login request: " + msg.statusText);
    });
```

The problem I'm having is with Nancy's Forms-based authentication. I've walked through half a dozen different tutorials which all more or less do the same thing, as well as gone over the Nancy authentication demos. The one thing they all have in common is that they rely on the `LoginAndRedirect` extension method. I don't want to return a redirect. I want to return a result of the login attempt and let the client handle the navigation.

The IUserMapper implementation I'm using:

```
public class UserMapper : IUserMapper
{
     public IUserIdentity GetUserFromIdentifier(Guid identifier, NancyContext context)
     {
        // Don't care who at this point, just want ANY user...
        return AuthenticatedUser {UserName = "admin"};
     }
}
```

The relevant part of my LoginModule action:

```
var result = _userMapper.ValidateUser(input.AccessCode);

if (result.Guid != null) this.Login(UserMapper.GUID_ADMIN, expiry);

return Response.AsJson(result.Response);
```

but for subsequent requests `Context.CurrentUser` is always null.

If I add the following method to the Nancy.Demo.Authentication.Forms sample it reproduces the behaviour I'm seeing in my own project, leading me to believe LoginWithoutRedirect doesn't work how I expected.

```
Get["/login/{name}"] = x =>
{
    Guid? userGuid = UserDatabase.ValidateUser(x.Name, "password");
    this.LoginWithoutRedirect(userGuid.Value, DateTime.Now.AddYears(2));
    return "Logged in as " + x.Name + " now <a href='~/secure'>see if it worked</a>";
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem turns out to be that `Context.CurrentUser` with FormsAuthentication is dependent upon a cookie which isn't set if you don't return the `NancyModule.Login()` response.

```
var result = _userMapper.ValidateUser(input.AccessCode);             
if (result.IsSuccess) {
     this.LoginWithoutRedirect(result.Guid);
}
return Response.AsJson(result);
```

In this example, the `LoginWithoutRedirect` call returns a `Response` object with the cookie set. To handle this in an Ajax scenario I've had to add a AuthToken property to the `LoginAjaxResponse` class, then pass the cookie like so:

```
var result = _userMapper.ValidateUser(input.AccessCode);             
var response = Response.AsJson(result);
if (result.IsSuccess) {
     var authResult = this.LoginWithoutRedirect(result.Guid);
     result.AuthToken = authResult.Cookies[0].Value;
}
return Response.AsJson(result);
```

On the client, the Ajax response handler changes to (assuming use of [jQuery cookie plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/):

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/login',
    type: "POST",
    data: { UserName: username }
    }).done(function (response) {
    if (response.IsSuccess) {
        showSuccess();
        $.cookie("_ncfa", response.AuthToken); // <-- the magic happens here
        document.location.href = response.RedirectUrl;
        return;
    }
    showError(response.ErrorMessage);
}).fail(function (msg) {
   showError("Unable to process login request: " + msg.statusText);
});
```

The AuthToken is the GUID which has been encrypted and base64-encoded. Subsequent requests with `this.RequiresAuthentication()` enabled will first check for this auth token cookie.

- If no "_ncfa" cookie is present,the `UserMapper`'s `GetUserFromIdentifier()` is never called.
- If the value in `Context.Request.Cookies["_ncfa"]` does not result in a valid GUID when base64-decoded and decrypted, `GetUserFromIdentifier()` is never called.
- If `GetUserFromIdentifier()` isn't called, `Context.CurrentUser` is never set.

If you want the source for a working example it's on [GitHub](https://github.com/nathanchere/Nancy.Demo.FormsAuthentication.Ajax).

Comment: You can also set the cookie in the response, so to avoid having to set it in the client.

example:
    
    foreach (var c in authResult.Cookies) response.Cookies.Add (c);

Answer (score 2):

LoginAndRedirect is only one option, there are equivalent methods for not redirecting (LoginWithoutRedirect), or one that picks up on whether it's an AJAX request and handles it appropriately (Login). The same applies to logging out.

This is all covered, in detail, in [the documentation](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Forms-Authentication).

Comment: If I understand the documentation correctly, the example I provided using `Login()` should in turn call `LoginWithouRedirect` since it's an AJAX request. I have also tried using `LoginWithouRedirect` explicitly and the `Context.CurrentUser` isn't set.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't falling foul of the encryption setup? Is the cookie being received and sent with every request?

Comment: I'm not doing any encryption setup. I'm pretty confident now that it's not behaving how it says on the box as I've taken the Nancy.Demo.Authentication.Forms code and added a new login action which exhibits the same behaviour I'm seeing in my own project - have updated the question accordingly

Comment: Sorry, I completely missed the fact you weren't returning the response from that method - yes, doing that is required as that's how the cookie is set - if you don't set the cookie it's not going to work. You should be able to handle all your login scenarios just using the status code, you shouldn't need to manually create JSON responses at all.